# ANY in postgresql gives weird error

Tags: postgresql, array

when I do:

```
SELECT ARRAY[4]
```

I get

```
array
integer[]
------
{4}
```

and if I do:

```
select *
from b
where b.ID = ANY (array [4])
```

That works.

Now, something else:

```
select array_agg(4)
```

I get:

```
array_agg
integer[]
-------
{4}
```

But if I do:

```
select *
from b
where b.ID = ANY (array_agg(4))
```

i get:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

Any explanation How can it be?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31292583/330315